# taxonomy list display custom post count

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, count, list

I use `$term->count` to display post count but it displays the total count of all type of custom posts attached to taxonomy...

I just want to display the count of only a specific custom post type attached to taxonomy

```
$icon = get_field('logo', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id); 
                        $va_category_HTML .= '<li class="logolar" '.$carrentActiveClass.'>' .'<a class="rownum">' .$i++. '</a>'. '</a>';
                        $va_category_HTML .= sprintf('<img src="%s" />', $icon) . '</a>';
                        $va_category_HTML .='<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                        if (empty( $instance['wcw_hide_count'] )) {
                        $va_category_HTML .='<span class="post-count">'.$term->count.'</span>';
                        }

                        $va_category_HTML .='</li>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes this annoying is that the `count` is a `wp_term_taxonomy` table.

So the way to do this is a custom query:

```
function wpse340250_term_count( WP_Term $term, $post_type) {
    $q_args = [
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'nopaging' => true, // no limit, pagination
        'fields' => 'ids', // only return post id's instead of full WP_Post objects will speed up
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    ];
    $term_count = get_posts($q_args);

    return count($term_count);
}
```

So change the line to:

```
$va_category_HTML .='<span class="post-count">'.wpse340250_term_count($term, 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE').'</span>';
```

Just set the correct posttype.

Comment: i am so grateful to you. thank you so much..
just one more question.. order by still run according to total post count

Comment: $terms = get_terms( $instance['wcw_taxonomy_type'], array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC','hide_empty'=>0 ));

Comment: That is a separate question, if this answers the main question accept is as such. And open a new question. Maybe someone else knows this without researching it.

Comment: ok i will open new question.. thank you very much you made unbelivable happy.. god save you

Comment: If this answer helped this question please mark is as answered, left to a answer is a green checkmark.

Comment: ok of course/ thanks

Comment: please janw, if you have time, take a look at this topic.https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340496/taxonomy-list-order-by-a-specific-custom-post-type-count I promise never annoy you any more.. thanks.