# How to show custom post count in archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, count

I want to show custom post count of taxonomies in archive page..not all custom post counts of taxonomy, i just want to show videos custom post count. because taxonomies have two custom post type. videos and trailers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taxonomy list display custom post count](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340250/taxonomy-list-display-custom-post-count)

Comment: sir i tried that code after you marked this question as dublicate. But it show nothing